# Publishing 100 GB of data to a web portal

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping

I have to publish 100 GB of data to a web portal in 2 or 3 layers using open source technologies.

The data comes from ArcGIS and are polygon features. So, I can save/export the data to any ArcGIS supported format.

I am thinking:

- Bring the data from ArcGIS in .shp format, so there would be multiple shape files for each layer.
- Use Geoserver to publish the vector data to WMS format
- Use WMS in Leaflet to add the data to map

As I have 100GB of data, can the web map be fast enough to zoom and pan and search?

Is there any better way to do my task?

Comment: the .dbf  part of a shapefile has a limit of 2gb... https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm#:~:text=Shapefile%20extensions-,Geometry%20limitations,roughly%2070%20million%20point%20features.

Comment: Please provide more informations (like the use case and constraints, what do you mean by "a portal", ...) in it's current state your question is unanswerable (@Mapperz I think that mean they have at least 50 shapefile...)

Comment: Also unclear is whether you mean Esri's  ArcGIS Enterprise Portal or some other portal.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please open it.

Comment: The "2-3 layers" and 100GB of shapefile don't sync up. It would take at least 50 shapefile layers to store that much data.

Comment: Yes, each layer would have many shape files. If this approach is not efficient, then please suggest a better approach. From ArcGIS, we can export data to any ArcGIS supported format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) will have no problem displaying the data, speed mostly depends on how you store the data, the best option is usually a well designed and indexed [PostGIS](https://postgis.org) database table.

If you need more speed (or just want to save cpu cycles) you can use [GeoWebCache](https://www.geowebcache.org/index.html) (built in to GeoServer) to cache the map tiles that are being requested by clients so they only need be drawn once.